# Laravel Upgrade throwing error, how to upgrade from 5.7 to 6.2?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-6.2

I am having Laravel 5.7.* for now. I tried upgrading it by making a change to the composer.json file. When I run composer update I get following errors:

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev requires laravel/nexmo-notification-channel ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/nexmo-notification-channel[1.0.x-dev, v1.0.0, v1.0.1].
    - laravel/nexmo-notification-channel v1.0.1 requires nexmo/client ^1.0 -> satisfiable by nexmo/client[1.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel/nexmo-notification-channel v1.0.0 requires nexmo/client ^1.0 -> satisfiable by nexmo/client[1.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel/nexmo-notification-channel 1.0.x-dev requires nexmo/client ^1.0 -> satisfiable by nexmo/client[1.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Conclusion: remove gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.1
    - Installation request for gloudemans/shoppingcart ^2.6 -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.6.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0 requires illuminate/events 5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.15, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev], illuminate/events[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v5.7.15].
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1].
```

Is this because of gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0 package? Or the error because of something else. I upgrade PHP to 7.2 and also Nexmo to 2.0
If I have to remove gloudemans package, what should be an alternative to it?

Comment: Are you trying to go from `5.7` directly to `6.2`? That might not be a good idea. Thankfully, you can follow the upgrade guides: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade (for 5.7 to 5.8) and https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade (for 5.8 to 6.x)

Comment: This package `gloudemans/shoppingcart` does not exist. Try remove it from your `composer.json` and try again

Comment: that package does not support Laravel 6, it specifically depends upon laravel components in the 5.x version range

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone for your comments. I have removed the gloudemans package. Now I will do the step by step upgrade i.e 5.7 to 5.8 then 5.8 to 6.0 and then 6.0 to 6.2